# Android custom compound views, how to re-use attributes?

Tags: android

Hello I made this compound view that contains a text view (to display error or advice) and a edit text (for input)

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guidanceOrError"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Please input 6 characters and 1 number"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_guidance_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/login_editText_padding"
        tools:hint="@string/user_name"/>

</merge>
```

And this is me using it in an activity layout

```
 <com.ersen.test.widgets.ValidationInputField
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_editText_top_margin"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

My problem is that attributes like hint and inputType are being ignored.
This is because in my `init(AttributeSet attrs)` method I am not getting the attributes out

```
 if(attrs != null){
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.???);
            a.recycle();
        }
```

**My question is how can I use attributes that already exist? I do not want to re-create them**

Please help me and thanks for reading

**Edit 1** 
My compound view extends LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Guess you're talking about a `CustomView`.

However you should `declare-styleable` in `attrs.xml` and use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ValidationInputField">
        <attr name="android:hint"/>
        <attr name="android:inputType"/>            
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

So, edit your `init` method like this:

```
    if(attrs != null){
                TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ValidationInputField);
                String hint = a.getString(R.styleable.ValidationInputField_android_hint);
                 int inputType = a.getInt(R.styleable.ValidationInputField_android_inputType,0);
                // set these two values in your EditText programmatically   
                EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputField);
               editText.setHint(hint);
               editText.setInputType(inputType);
                a.recycle();
                }
```